# How to return an optional tuple

Tags: swift, tuples

I have function that finds two ranges for a substring in the string1 and string2, and it returns the tuple

```
(Range<String.Index>!, Range<String.Index>!)
```

I need tuples to store them later in an array. The problem comes when no ranges were found. How to deal with this, what function should return – empty tuple or tuple with nil (nil, nil) ?

Comment: Use optionals?  `(Range<String.Index>?, Range<String.Index>?)`

Comment: @JAL Thanks, it works !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be returning optionals rather than force unwrapping each `Range` object in your tuple:

```
(Range<String.Index>?, Range<String.Index>?)
```

Answer (score 3):

It's better to make the tuple itself optional, rather than return a tuple full of `nil`s when the function fails:

```
func myFunction() -> (value1: Type, value2: Type)?
{
   if (it_hasnt_worked) {
      return nil
   }
}
```

Note the question mark comes after the tuple in the function declaration.